# Import variables into a class

Tags: python

I have a file that contains all the variables my application needs:

## config.py

```
AWS_KEY=1234
AWS_SECRET=5678
```

## modules/db.py

```
from project.libraries import boto as boto

conn = boto.connect_dynamodb(
  aws_access_key_id=AWS_KEY
  aws_secret_access_key=AWS_SECRET)
```

How can I get the variables from config.py into modules/db.py?
(Or, is this the wrong approach?)

Thanks.

Comment: Did you already try `import config` and check whether `config.AWS_KEY` exists?

Comment: `from config import AWS_KEY, AWS_SECRET`?

Comment: Thanks, that did it. Didn't know about the config.* syntax.

Comment: Be careful "config" is a very generic name, so there is a good chance you might import a different file called "config.py" if it is found earlier in your path

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### modules/db.py

```
import config
AWS_KEY = config.AWS_KEY
```

Alternatively,

```
from config import AWS_KEY, AWS_SECRET
```

Or, if you want to keep the config prefix,

```
import config
print config.AWS_KEY
```

Forgive me if you've already done so, but have you read about [python modules](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/modules.html)?